# Reference third party dlls in aspnet core app on top of net452 framework

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

When I try to reference third party dll's (based on full .net framework) I get this error:

> .NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies
>   in this release. To reference other assemblies, they need to be
>   included in a NuGet package and reference that package.

I need to referenece about 30 third party dll's, can I create just one NuGet package inlcluding all these dlls? Will this work if framework referenced is .net452 and dll ara based on earlier versions?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx

Comment: I've managed to reference framework assemblies in core but now get error "CSharpAddImportCodeFixProvider encountered an error and has been disabled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could include all these third party dlls in one NuGet package. Please refer to following steps.

1. Download [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/releases/view/624769).
2. Open NuGet Package Explorer and choose "Create a new package".
3. Click the "Content" menu and choose "Add -> Existing File" to add the dlls into this package.
4. Click the "File" menu and choose "Save" to save this package on your local machine.
5. Add this local package source into Visual Studio through Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources.

And I also tested .net4.5.2 and other previous version dlls, all of them are working fine.